# FindViewById returns null after StartActivity

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, findviewbyid

I write an Android application with Xamarin. I have a start activity that shows start screen and initializes an application. When the application is initialized I finish the activity and start the next one. Here is method `StartActivity.OnCreate`:

```
        protected override async void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.StartScreen);

            // initializing app
            string status = await DownloadSomeString();                 
            Finish();

            // starting a main activity after initialization
            var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
            StartActivity(intent);
        }
```

And here is method `MainActivity.OnCreate`:

```
    protected override async void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {            
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.MainActivity);                

        await Task.Delay(3000); // #1 
        // if the prevoius line is commented the textview is null
        var textView = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.Text);
        textView.Text = "Some text";
    }
```

If I comment line #1 from this method `FindViewById` return null. I suppose it takes a few time to iniialize UI for MainActivity but it is pretty strange for me because I supposed UI elements should be already initialized after calling `SetContentView`. Maybe anyone has idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: `If I comment line #1 ` which line is that?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko  I talk about line `await Task.Delay(3000); // #1 `

Comment: you should not need that line. It should run synchronously (UI initialization I mean). Try removing that delay, and removing `async` from method

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko if I remove this line I have `NullReferenceException` in line `textView.Text = "Some text";` 'cause textView is null

Comment: are you sure that your `Resource.Layout.MainActivity` has `Resource.Id.Text`?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko Yes I'm sure. And If I do not comment line #1 then `FindViewById` return textView and it is not null

Comment: also *probably* you need to move `Finish()`of the first activity after you `startActivity()`

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko I moved it before StartActivity when I faced this problem first time. Previously I firstly called StartActivity and then Finish and NRE happened

Comment: Are you sure neither `base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);` nor `SetContentView(Resource.Layout.MainActivity);` is awaitable?  Seems to me the objects are still being initialized when you code already tries to find by id. This is perhaps why the 3 second wait period solves this problem?

Comment: @BjornDeRijcke Yes both of them are not awaitable

Comment: 1) Remove the `Finish()` in the first activity (or move it after the StartActivity) 2) Remove the `Task.Delay`, `SetContentView` is synchronous on the layout inflation.

Comment: `StartActivity (intent)` behavior is best not to write in the `onCreate ()` method directly, the application interface loading is also need time, according to the complexity of the interface and the hardware environment are fluctuating, you can try to test in the Button click method or `OnResume()` method.